# How to keep the check button toggle while changing scenes in Godot 4.1

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm working on a game project, and I want to make options menu, so when I added the Fullscreen button, I found it becomes unchecked while changing scenes, I tried to fix it with autoload scripts and config, I used Chat GPT too!, but till now I can't fix it, so if you can help me I'll be thankful for you.

My Code:

```
extends Control


var save_path = "user://Config.cfg" # Use "user://" for user-specific data
var config = ConfigFile.new()
var load_response = config.load(save_path)
var fullscreen_setting = config.get_value("Display", "Fullscreen")
var FullScreen_button_pressed : bool = config.get_value("Display", "Fullscreen")
# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.

func _ready():
    if config.load(save_path) == OK:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = true # Check if fullscreen setting is true
    else:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = false # Default value if loading fails

        
func _on_back_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://GameData/Main.tscn")


func _on_FullScreen_button_toggled(FullScreen_button_pressed: bool):


    if FullScreen_button_pressed:
        DisplayServer.window_set_mode(DisplayServer.WINDOW_MODE_FULLSCREEN)
    else:
        DisplayServer.window_set_mode(DisplayServer.WINDOW_MODE_WINDOWED)
    
    config.set_value("Display", "Fullscreen", FullScreen_button_pressed) # Set the value in the configuration file
    config.save(save_path) # Save the configuration file
```

My Autoload script:

```
extends Node2D

var config = ConfigFile.new()
var save_path = "user://config.cfg"
var fullscreen = false

func _ready():
    if config.load(save_path) == OK:
        fullscreen = config.get_value("Display", "Fullscreen", false)
        if fullscreen:
            DisplayServer.window_set_mode(DisplayServer.WINDOW_MODE_FULLSCREEN)
        else:
            DisplayServer.window_set_mode(DisplayServer.WINDOW_MODE_WINDOWED)
    else:
        print("Failed to load the configuration file!")
        # Handle the error loading the configuration file
```

Thank you in advance.

I was trying to add a Fullscreen check button without, but I found it become unchecked while changing scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Starting by reading your code, it says:

```
func _ready():
    if config.load(save_path) == OK:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = true # Check if fullscreen setting is true
    else:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = false # Default value if loading fails
```

If the configuration was loaded, set `FullScreen_button_pressed` to `true`. Otherwise set it to `false`.

Is that what you want? I don't think that is what you want.

In fact, it appears you already doing what you want:

```
var FullScreen_button_pressed : bool = config.get_value("Display", "Fullscreen")
```

---

Let us move that to `_ready`:

```
var FullScreen_button_pressed : bool

func _ready():
    if config.load(save_path) == OK:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = config.get_value("Display", "Fullscreen")
    else:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = false # Default value if loading fails
```

Now if the configuration loaded, we set `FullScreen_button_pressed` to the value from the configuration. Otherwise we set it to `false`.

This leaves the chance that the configuration loaded but it didn't have the value we try to read. Looking at the documentation of [`get_value`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_configfile.html#class-configfile-method-get-value) we find that you can set a default value, let us use that:

```
var FullScreen_button_pressed : bool

func _ready():
    if config.load(save_path) == OK:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = config.get_value("Display", "Fullscreen", false)
    else:
        FullScreen_button_pressed = false # Default value if loading fails
```